# mapStateToProps not updating component on change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

New to react/redux. Wondering why my component is not refreshing on the fired action. Also not sure whether reducer is a good place to manipulate the store but it is pure so it should work.

What happens is that action is fired and store is updated. But the clicked item is not updating (props update shoud add class `added` to it)

**Component:**

Referencing rcm_data by Id to toggle class `added`, onClick fire action

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addRateCard } from "../actions";

import "./RcmEditor.css";

class RcmEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="slds-table slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Rate Card Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {group.rateCardIds.map(rcId => {
            return (
              <tr
                className={
                  "ed-group-rc " +
                  (this.props.rcm_data[rcId].added ? "added" : "")
                }
                key={rcId}
                onClick={() =>
                  this.props.addRateCard(this.props.rcm_data[rcId])
                }
              >
                <td colSpan="100">{this.props.rcm_data[rcId].Name}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addRateCard
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { rcm_data: state.rcm_data, group_data: state.group_data };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(RcmEditor);
```

**Actions:**

```
const ADD_RATE_CARD = "ADD_RATE_CARD";

export const addRateCard = rateCard => ({ type: ADD_RATE_CARD, payload: rateCard });
```

**Reducer:**

Copy state (just a precaution), increment added_count property of group_data and change added property of rcm_data referenced by action. payload Id, return a new state. Everything seems pure here

```
const initialState = {
    rcm_data: {},
    group_data: {},
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    case "ADD_RATE_CARD":

        let _state = { ...state };
        let rateCard = action.payload;

        _state.group_data[rateCard.GroupName].added_count++;
        _state.rcm_data[rateCard.Id].added = true;

        let data = {
            rcm_data: _state.rcm_data,
            group_data: _state.group_data
        };

        return { ...state, rcm_data: _state.rcm_data, group_data: _state.group_data };
    default:
        return state;
   }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: `not sure whether reducer is a good place to manipulate store`. I personally prefer that logic should go in actions and reducer should only give new state. You can use redux-thunk in your actions to add logic

Comment: I tought that accessing store in action creators is not best practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reducer copies objects (`rcm_data` and `group_data`) and mutates them.

Redux compares shallowly - using the same object refs there is no difference then no update/rerender.

Simply create a new sub-objects, sth like:

```
    let data = {
        rcm_data: {...state.rcm_data},
        group_data: {...state.group_data}
    };
    data.group_data[rateCard.GroupName].added_count++;
    data.rcm_data[rateCard.Id].added = true;
    return data
```

Comment: This worked altough I dont see difference with what I did

Comment: New  `rcm_data` and `group_data` objects (with updated data) created - used in `mapStateToProps` - new for redux `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: Will have more close look into it. I changed return statement to `return {...state, ...data};` which works as well. In case I add more states later on